# How to use a service properly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

i I've been testing with Angular and i have a issue.
I have an external json file and i use this:

```
if ($localStorage.films && $localStorage.films.length!=0) {
    $scope.films=$localStorage.films;
}else{
    $http.get("json/films.json")
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.films = res.data;                
    });
    $scope.$storage=$localStorage.$default({
            films: ""
    });
}
```

This is in my controller and i want to move it to a service. Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are.

Services are in place to provide you with objects when you need them. It is also a 'best practice' to encapsulate the functionality of class to single responsibility. in your case => service to fetch obj, controller to serve the data

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I'll prove it.